# (Nodejs + Restify) Can't set headers after they are sent - promise rejection warning

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, restify

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
**This error happens when I hitting the API continuously or again hitting the API before the request got completed.**
Referred many solutions but cant able to get the proper answer.pls, Help me to sort out.

```
exports.getRecords = function(req, res) {

        db.task(t => {
                return t.batch([
                    t.any(selectQuery),
                    t.any(recordCountQuery)
                ]);
            })
            .then(data => {

                //create a formatted object based on the two queries with recordCount
                var output = {};

                output.meta = data[1][0];
                let petData = data[0];

                /*
                 * Checks If the pet details available and then processing the pets Data
                 * To get the existing image URL.
                 */

                if (!util.isNullOrUndefined(petData)) {
                    //Iterating over the Array of pets and process each pets with promises()
                    Promise.all(petData.map(pet => {

                            //Processing each pet
                            return processUtil.getvalidData(pet)
                                .then(pet => pet);
                        }))
                        .then(results => {
                            //After processing all the pets send the output
                            output.data = results;
                            res.json(output);
                        })
                };
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                if (util.isError(err)) {
                    res.error('NotFoundError', err);
                } // return 404
                else {
                    res.error('InternalServerError', err);
                }; //else 500

            });
    };
```

Here is console log for the two responses

Response log for single hit

```
    "15" "TRACE" "services-data" "lynd-PC" "sr"  "4596ec40" "" "GET" "/data/2" "request received"
    "16" "TRACE" "services-data" "lynd-PC" ""    "4596ec40" "" "GET" "/data/2" ""
    "17" "TRACE" "services-data" "lynd-PC" ""    "4596ec40" "" "GET" "/data/2" ""
    "18" "TRACE" "services-data" "lynd-PC" "ss"  "4596ec40" "200" "GET" "/data/2" "response sent"
```

Response log when we twice hitting the API before the request got completed.

```
"15" "TRACE" "services-data" "lynd-PC" "sr"  "1a85afb7" "" "GET" "/data/2" "request received"
"15" "TRACE" "services-data" "lynd-PC" ""    "1a85afb7" "" "GET" "/data/2" ""
"16" "TRACE" "services-data" "lynd-PC" ""    "1a85afb7" "" "GET" "/data/2" ""
"17" "TRACE" "services-data" "lynd-PC" "ss"  "1a85afb7" "500" "GET" "/data/2" "response sent"
"18" "TRACE" "services-data" "lynd-PC" ""    "1a85afb7" "" "GET" "/data/2" ""
(node:3860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Comment: What is your database?  Are `db.task()` and `t.batch()` fully safe when multiple invocations are in flight at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, there is no reject handler for the `Promise.all()` in your code.  You can chain it to the parent promise chain (which does have a reject handler) by just changing this:

```
Promise.all(petData.map(pet => {
```

to this:

```
return Promise.all(petData.map(pet => {
```

So, that will fix one opportunity for an unhandled rejection.  Or, you can add your own reject handle to the `Promise.all()` promise if you'd rather have a separate reject handler for it.

---

It also appears you have several code paths that would send no response.  If this condition:

```
if (!util.isNullOrUndefined(petData)) {
```

is not satisified (meaning it does not go into the `if` block), then your code will not send any response which is typically a coding mistake since every request needs exactly one response to be sent.